Git remote commands suddenly gotten extremely slow the past weeks (some times takes minutes to do simple pull/push)
It does not seem to be related to what network I am on.
git -v: git version 2.39.5 (Apple Git-154)

MacOS 15.1.1 (24B91), Mac M1
Below is an example of a simple git pull command on the repo to Github.
GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git pull                          

19:42:33.503780 exec-cmd.c:139          trace: resolved executable path from Darwin stack: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
19:42:33.504477 exec-cmd.c:238          trace: resolved executable dir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
19:42:33.508356 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git pull
19:42:33.520224 read-cache.c:2447       performance: 0.010823000 s:  read cache .git/index
19:42:33.521022 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: git fetch --update-head-ok
19:42:33.528755 exec-cmd.c:139          trace: resolved executable path from Darwin stack: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git
19:42:33.529299 exec-cmd.c:238          trace: resolved executable dir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core
19:42:33.530077 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git fetch --update-head-ok
19:42:33.531937 read-cache.c:2447       performance: 0.001002000 s:  read cache .git/index
19:42:33.538011 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_PROTOCOL=version=2 ssh -o SendEnv=GIT_PROTOCOL git@github.com 'git-upload-pack '\''/REDACTED/REDACTED.git'\'''
19:43:05.101462 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< version 2
19:43:05.101643 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< agent=git/github-6101d4665181
19:43:05.101655 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< ls-refs=unborn
19:43:05.101661 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< fetch=shallow wait-for-done filter
19:43:05.101667 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< server-option
19:43:05.101672 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< object-format=sha1
19:43:05.101677 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< 0000
19:43:05.101699 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> command=ls-refs
19:43:05.101712 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> agent=git/2.39.5.(Apple.Git-154)
19:43:05.101719 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> object-format=sha1
19:43:05.101723 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> 0001
19:43:05.101728 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> peel
19:43:05.101733 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> symrefs
19:43:05.101739 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> unborn
19:43:05.101758 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> ref-prefix refs/heads/
19:43:05.101773 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> ref-prefix refs/heads/master
19:43:05.101784 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> ref-prefix refs/tags/

[... REFS OUTPUT REDACTED FOR PRIVACY ...]
Here are around 600 lines of output that I've redacted for privacy. The lines are similar to this:

  19:43:05.478566 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch< 343422a06c5a26a18eb527e994727390cab8a6db refs/heads/my_user/my_new_feature

19:43:05.595563 pkt-line.c:80           packet:        fetch> 0000
19:43:05.739401 run-command.c:1524      run_processes_parallel: preparing to run up to 1 tasks
19:43:05.740357 run-command.c:1551      run_processes_parallel: done
19:43:05.740372 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
19:43:05.752328 exec-cmd.c:139          trace: resolved executable path from Darwin stack: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git
19:43:05.754504 exec-cmd.c:238          trace: resolved executable dir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core
19:43:05.756203 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
19:43:05.758630 trace.c:411             performance: 0.003305000 s: git command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git maintenance run --auto --no-quiet
19:43:05.759269 trace.c:411             performance: 32.229675000 s: git command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git fetch --update-head-ok
19:43:05.765203 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: git merge FETCH_HEAD
19:43:05.773504 exec-cmd.c:139          trace: resolved executable path from Darwin stack: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git
19:43:05.774109 exec-cmd.c:238          trace: resolved executable dir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core
19:43:05.774914 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git merge FETCH_HEAD
19:43:05.781515 read-cache.c:2447       performance: 0.003627000 s:  read cache .git/index
Already up to date.
19:43:05.783173 trace.c:411             performance: 0.008771000 s: git command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git merge FETCH_HEAD
19:43:05.783602 trace.c:411             performance: 32.276901000 s: git command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git pull

I don't know how to interpret the log. What is it telling me exactly? The big chunk of time seems to be spend at: 19:42:33.538011 run-command.c:655       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_PROTOCOL=version=2 ssh -o SendEnv=GIT_PROTOCOL git@github.com 'git-upload-pack '\''/REDACTED/REDACTED.git'\''' - what does that indicate? What other things could I do to test this or gain further insights?
UPDATE from comment:
ssh -Tvvv git@github.com

OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/[username]/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/[username]/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug3: /Users/[username]/.ssh/config line 6: Including file /Users/[username]/Programming/[project]/provisioning/inventory/production/ssh.config depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/[username]/Programming/[project]/provisioning/inventory/production/ssh.config
debug3: /Users/[username]/.ssh/config line 7: Including file /Users/[username]/Programming/[project]/[project]/.production_servers_ssh.config depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/[username]/Programming/[project]/[project]/.production_servers_ssh.config
debug1: /Users/[username]/Programming/[project]/[project]/.production_servers_ssh.config line 4: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_addr: could not resolve name github.com as address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
debug3: resolve_canonicalize: attempting "github.com" => "github.com.[domain]."
debug3: resolve_host: lookup github.com.[domain]:22
debug1: ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com.[domain]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: host github.com not found in any suffix
debug1: hostname canonicalisation enabled, will re-parse configuration
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/[username]/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/[username]/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug2: add_identity_file: ignoring duplicate key ~/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: /Users/[username]/.ssh/config line 6: Including file /Users/[username]/Programming/[project]/provisioning/inventory/production/ssh.config depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/[username]/Programming/[project]/provisioning/inventory/production/ssh.config
debug3: /Users/[username]/.ssh/config line 7: Including file /Users/[username]/Programming/[project]/[project]/.production_servers_ssh.config depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/[username]/Programming/[project]/[project]/.production_servers_ssh.config
debug1: /Users/[username]/Programming/[project]/[project]/.production_servers_ssh.config line 4: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: channel_clear_timeouts: clearing
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version c541a10de
debug1: compat_banner: no match: c541a10de
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts:253
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts:254
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts:255
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts:256
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 4 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug3: kex_choose_conf: will use strict KEX ordering
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:[redacted]
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts:253
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts:254
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts:255
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts:256
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 4 keys from github.com
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts:253
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug3: kex_input_ext_info: extension server-sig-algs
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.[random]/Listeners'
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:[redacted] explicit agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:[redacted] explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:[redacted] explicit agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with RSA SHA256:[redacted]
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:[redacted]
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to github.com ([ip address]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new session [client-session] (inactive timeout: 0)
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received RSA key SHA256:[redacted]
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ECDSA key SHA256:[redacted]
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: received ED25519 key SHA256:[redacted]
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts for github.com / (none)
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts:253
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-rsa key at /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts:254
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key at /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts:255
debug3: hostkeys_find: found ssh-ed25519 key at /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts:256
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts2 for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /Users/[username]/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug3: client_input_hostkeys: 3 server keys: 0 new, 3 retained, 0 incomplete match. 0 to remove
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 6 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 6 IP_TOS 0x20
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env __CFBundleIdentifier
debug3: Ignored env XPC_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env XPC_SERVICE_NAME
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM
debug3: Ignored env TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env TERM_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env RBENV_SHELL
debug3: Ignored env PROMPT
debug3: Ignored env ASDF_DIR
debug3: Ignored env EDITOR
debug3: Ignored env VISUAL
debug3: Ignored env NVM_DIR
debug3: Ignored env NVM_CD_FLAGS
debug3: Ignored env PYENV_ROOT
debug3: Ignored env rvm_prefix
debug3: Ignored env rvm_path
debug3: Ignored env rvm_bin_path
debug3: Ignored env rvm_version
debug3: Ignored env GEM_HOME
debug3: Ignored env GEM_PATH
debug3: Ignored env MY_RUBY_HOME
debug3: Ignored env IRBRC
debug3: Ignored env RUBY_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env TMPDIR
debug3: Ignored env NVM_BIN
debug3: Ignored env NVM_INC
debug3: Ignored env rvm_alias_expanded
debug3: Ignored env rvm_bin_flag
debug3: Ignored env rvm_docs_type
debug3: Ignored env rvm_gemstone_package_file
debug3: Ignored env rvm_gemstone_url
debug3: Ignored env rvm_niceness
debug3: Ignored env rvm_nightly_flag
debug3: Ignored env rvm_only_path_flag
debug3: Ignored env rvm_pretty_print_flag
debug3: Ignored env rvm_proxy
debug3: Ignored env rvm_quiet_flag
debug3: Ignored env rvm_ruby_bits
debug3: Ignored env rvm_ruby_file
debug3: Ignored env rvm_ruby_make
debug3: Ignored env rvm_ruby_make_install
debug3: Ignored env rvm_ruby_mode
debug3: Ignored env rvm_script_name
debug3: Ignored env rvm_sdk
debug3: Ignored env rvm_silent_flag
debug3: Ignored env rvm_use_flag
debug3: Ignored env rvm_delete_flag
debug3: Ignored env rvm_file_name
debug3: Ignored env rvm_ruby_alias
debug3: Ignored env rvm_sticky_flag
debug3: Ignored env rvm_system_flag
debug3: Ignored env rvm_user_flag
debug3: Ignored env rvm_ruby_string
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8"
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug1: pledge: fork
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 32000 rmax 35000
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 3
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 14
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 2
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 76
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 1
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 7 efd 9 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf_empty delayed efd 9/(96)
Hi [username]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug2: channel 0: written 96 to efd 9
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 8 efd 9 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 [session] r43 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/9 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x00/0x00)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Transferred: sent 2880, received 2840 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9434.4, received 9303.3
debug1: Exit status 1


Git starting SSH to be used as its transport — and it seems ssh is starting very slowly. Try ssh -Tvvv git@github.com to see if it's really so slow and why.

@phd done - yes - it was indeed very very slow - see my updated log of that...

It was hanging for about 30 seconds at: debug3: resolve_host: lookup github.com.[domain]:22

From your debug output, I can see that SSH is trying to resolve github.com as github.com.[domain].private, which is causing a delay because this domain doesn't exist. This is happening because of your SSH configuration.
The key issue appears in these lines:
debug2: resolve_addr: could not resolve name github.com as address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
debug3: resolve_canonicalize: attempting "github.com" => "github.com.[domain]."
debug3: resolve_host: lookup github.com.[domain]:22
debug1: ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com.[domain]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

This suggests that one of your SSH config files (likely in /Users/[username]/Programming/[project]/[project]/.production_servers_ssh.config or another included config) has a setting that's trying to append .[domain].private to hostnames.
To fix this:
Check your SSH config files for any settings like:
CanonicalizeHostname yes
CanonicalDomains [domain].private

You can either:
Remove these settings completely or add a specific host entry for GitHub.com before any wildcard (*) to bypass this:
Host github.com
  CanonicalizeHostname no

This should prevent SSH from trying to canonicalize the GitHub hostname and speed up your connection significantly.
